# Set unnumbered subsections in a table of contents à la Weinberg

Tags: table-of-contents, unnumbered-sections

I am very fond of the table of contents in the books of Weinberg, in which below the title of each section there is a list of themes with a separating symbol in between (see attached picture). I would like to reproduce that effect, but with slight differences: instead of the themes, I would like to put unnumbered subsections that are clickable and lead to the subsection in question. Also, instead of the squares I would like a full black dot, but I imagine that this is not the hardest part.

Here is how my article looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\Large \textsc{Title}} \\ \today \\
\end{center}
\hrulefill

\tableofcontents

\hrulefill

\section{Numbered section 1}

\subsection*{Unnumbered subsection}

Some text.

\subsection*{Unnumbered subsection}

Some text.

\section{Numbered section 2}

\subsection*{Unnumbered subsection}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have put no label so far in the subsections, but of course that is not a problem if I have to add some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all subsections are unnumbered, you can set `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` and then use `\subsection` without star. To format the subsection TOC entries you can load package `titletoc`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{subsection}
  [3.8em]
  {\normalfont}
  {\thecontentslabel}
  {}
  {}
  [\ \textbullet\ ]
  []
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 {\Large\textsc{ Title}\par}
\today \\
\end{center}
\noindent\hrulefill
\tableofcontents
\noindent\hrulefill
\section{Numbered section 1}
\subsection{Unnumbered subsection}
Some text.
\subsection{Unnumbered subsection}
Some text.
\section{Numbered section 2}
\subsection{Unnumbered subsection}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, I love it! Thanks a lot! Is it possible to remove the indent on the left of the "Unnumbered subsection" in the table of contents? To my mind, the best would be if they are align to the titles of the chapters, e.g. with "Numbered section 1". (note that in the Weinberg example, they are aligned with the numbers of the chapters)

Comment: Ah I just have to change the 3.8em... Sorry for the dumb question, your answer is perfect!